# Побитовые сдвиги в php

Tags: php, битовые-операции

Есть число размером 32 бита со значением 967968174. В число были записаны параметры  которые занимали 2, 3, 9, 9, 9 битов, и были записаны слева направо с использованием побитового сдвига влево "<<".
Не могу понять логики, почему при чтении значений, даже с учетом использования масок, используется побитовый сдвиг именно вправо? Ведь в теории, маски и так отвечают за свой диапазон битов.
`$form = (967968174 & 3);`
`$color = ((967968174 & 28) >> 2);`
`$angle = ((967968174 & 16352) >> 5);`
`$width = ((967968174 & 8372224) >> 14);`
`$height = ((967968174 & 4286578688) >> 23);`

Answer (score 1):

Если не сдвигать, то получатся оооочень большие значения. Посмотрите, например, что ляжет в переменную $angle без сдвига (1440 -> 0b0101 1010 0000) и со сдвигом (45 -> 0b0010 1101). Т.е. сдвиг и нужен как раз для того, чтобы получить исходные значения.

Пример: нам нужно записать параметр в виде числа 5 (0b101) в верхние биты 16-битного числа. Для этого мы применяем сдвиг влево на 13 и получаем 0b10100000 00000000). Потом мы еще записываем разные параметры и в итоге получаем что-то вроде 0b10100110 00111011). Чтобы достать первый параметр нам нужна маска 0b11100000 00000000 (0xE000). Применив её, получим 0b10100000 00000000.  Но нам-то нужно 5, а не это большое число. Вот тут и нужен сдвиг вправо на 13, как операция обратная сдвигу влево. Отбрасываем последние 13 нулей и получаем 0b101, т.е. то, что изначально записали.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Только вот еще, я не понимаю почему при чтении и записи используются сдвиги в разные стороны? Ведь при записи мы отталкиваемся от n битов справа используя сдвиг влево, а что происходит при чтении и сдвиге вправо?

Comment: Сдвиг влево - добавление нулей справа от числа (умножение на 2^n). Сдвиг вправо - отбрасывание последних n знаков (деление на 2^n).